# How to automate the task selection to week agenda in using Excel?

Tags: excel, automation, office365, office-automation

I have a table in excel with two sheets; the first `monthly_data_sheet` has the tasks and deadlines.

```
    A       B       C       D       E       F        G       H    I            J 
10  TASKS   ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...  START      DEADLINE
11  Task1   ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...  6/6/2022   30/6/2022
12  Task2   ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...  6/6/2022   30/6/2022
13  Task3   ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...  6/6/2022   30/6/2022
14  Task4   ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...  2/3/2022   30/3/2022
15  Task5   ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...  1/3/2022   30/3/2022
16  Task6   ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...  1/3/2022   30/3/2022
17  Task7   ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...  1/3/2022   30/3/2022
18  Task8   ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...  1/3/2022   30/3/2022
```

and I have another table,  the `weekly_data_sheet` which I want to bring all the tasks if the day of week is in the range of START and the DEADLINE.
For example, the first task, `task1` and `task2` and `task3` in `A11` should apear in the table 2, `weekly_data_sheet`, in C28 ,F28, I28, L28, O28, R28, T28.

```
            C               F               I              L             O             R             T       
25      06/06/2022      07/06/2022      08/06/2022     09/06/2022    10/06/2022     11/06/2022    12/06/2022            
26       Monday          Tuesday         wedsday        Thursday       Friday        Saturday       Sunday                      
27        June            June            June            June          June           June          June
28        Task1           Task1           Task1           Task1         Task1          Task1         Task1
29        Task2           Task2           Task2           Task2         Task2          Task2         Task2                      
30        Task3           Task3           Task3           Task3         Task3          Task3         Task3                      
31                                                                                                                              
32                                                                                                                              
33                                                                                                                              
34                                                                                                                              
35         ...             ...             ...             ...            ...           ...           ...
```

The line 25 changes every week.

I've tried the following rules:

```
C28 =FILTER(GanttChart!A:A;GanttChart!J:J=C25;"No results")

F28=FILTER(GanttChart!A:A;GanttChart!J:J=F25;"No results")

I28==FILTER(GanttChart!A:A;AND(GanttChart!I:I<=C25;GanttChart!J:J>=U25);"No results")

L28==FILTER(GanttChart!A:A;AND(C25>=GanttChart!J:J;GanttChart!K:K<=U25);"No results")

O28==FILTER(GanttChart!A:A;GanttChart!J:J=M25;"No results")

R28=FILTER(GanttChart!A:A;GanttChart!J:J=P25;"No results")

T28=FILTER(GanttChart!A:A;AND(GanttChart!I:I<=C25;GanttChart!J:J>=S25);"No results")
```

**Edited:**
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtPc07fC4QqykKZ2YB9Hu1AoPOnGkw?e=6d35oY

The table 1 is in the `GanttChart` and the second table is in the `Plan-Semana (2)`

using the suggested answer :
`=FILTER('GanttChart'!A:A;(C$25>='GanttChart'!I:I)*(C$25<='GanttChart'!J:J);'no results')`

The link of the online file
It's not working some one can help-me thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0):

Try `FILTER()` function with date comparison like-

```
=FILTER($A$2:$A$9,(C$12>=$I$2:$I$9)*(C$12<=$J$2:$J$9))
```

Then drag the formula to right as needed.

[image]

Comment: It  didn't work, the link for the office 365 `spread sheet` is the following: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtPc07fC4QqykKZ2YB9Hu1AoPOnGkw?e=loBsIY  I'm trying to get from the `GanttChart` to `Plan-Semana (2)`

Comment: Formula working fine. Criteria not matching with `J Column` data to `GanttChart` sheet. Try to change date in `M25` cell.

Comment: It doesn't work.  Because the columns retrieved are returning infinity results. Since I need to get the results that have a date. Not endless rows, which makes to spill.